# C# WPF Window IDisposable

Tags: c#, wpf

Правильно ли я понимаю, если у меня есть просто окно, то в `Dispose` мне нужно его просто закрыть, но если у меня в нем еще будут обьекты которые можно `Dispose` то нужно их всех уничтожить, а те которые нет просто засетить в `null` и вызвать `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`?

```
public partial class WelcomeWindow : Window, IDisposable {

  public WelcomeWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: А откуда у вас в окне Disposable-объекты?

Comment: @АндрейNOP у меня их нет, я в теории спросил

Comment: @АндрейNOP просто хочу использовать using для окон

Comment: `использовать using для окон` не надо так делать. У вас у окон есть спец события на открытие окна, закрытие окна и тд, вот при закрытии и очищайте все, что нужно

Comment: @tym32167 а если я их не использую? по факту this.Close их вызывает но у меня в окнах нету каких либо обьектов они только обращаются к Data Context

Comment: Кого не используете? А что диспозить собрались тогда? Обычная практика - диспозить вьюмодели при закрытии окна. Ну или перефразируйте вопрос, я не понял вас

Comment: Бизнес-логика не должна находиться в предоставлении, соответственно, никаких ресурсов окно не должно содержать. Просто закрывайте окно и его подберёт сборщик мусора, когда сочтет нужным.

Comment: [Посмотрите](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) детали о IDisposable реализации и disposable паттерне

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно реализовывать IDisposable, если в вашем типе нет вещей, которые нужно уничтожить вручную. Например указателей из низкоуровневой библиотеки. В общем, того, о чем сборщик мусора не знает. Реализация этого интерфейса есть в книге CLR via c# Рихтера.